# IBM Cloud Continuous Delivery Service is not recognized by toolchain

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, continuous-delivery, ibm-cloud-tools

I am trying to configure IBM Cloud Devops Continuous Delivery. 
I have the Build Stage configured. Build Stage runs fine and passes with a successful build. 
However Deploy Stage configured through template at the time of deployment did not run.
Every time when the page is refreshed getting Continuous Delivery service is not found and asking me to deploy a service. I see continuous delivery service is already deployed and configured to run.

[image: Following screenshot shows the error / warning that CD is not recognized]
[image: Following screenshot shows that CD is deployed]

Comment: Facing the same problem from last one week.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you're running into some trouble here. Provided you have an instance of Continuous Delivery in the same resource group as the toolchain & pipeline, the UI should not be throwing (and enforcing) a "Continuous Delivery service required" message at you. It sounds like you do have an instance of CD, so we're looking into the problem at our end of things.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I do have CD instance deployed. Attached screenshot for reference.

Comment: Facing the same problem from last one week.